# Build android project using Ant

Tags: android, ant, build

I need to make an auto build system. I have a library project and 5 other projects that references this library project. My rquirement is like if I type "ant project_name" in command prompt corresponding project should be build. I have downloaded Ant in my system. But I dont know how to script it and where to create the script. I have gone through many tutorials. But did not get an idea. I am new to Ant. Please help me.

**EDIT**
Where i need to write the script to build the project?can anyone give me an example of building a project using Ant?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do a good google search.

Here's a thorough walkthrough:

- [Tutorial on Building via ANT (step by step)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildAnt/article.html)
- [Further information about this for the developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)

Comment: i have already gone through these links.but i did not get the proper idea.

Comment: which portion do you have problem in understanding?Point out that portion in an edit to your question so that it is specific.Otherwise,you're not getting any answers this way.

Comment: "Tutorial on Building via ANT (step by step)" this link gives error page not found.